# The importance of the hybrid babies on BSG (RDM)

Tags: battlestar-galactica, cylon

In the RDM Battlestar series, it was a given that the 'skin job' Cylons were trying to procreate and had been unsuccessful.

Because of their failed attempts, Helo and Boomer's daughter Hera was given GREAT importance among the Cylons as an actual physical offspring of a Cylon.

I don't remember there ever being any such great importance however placed on Galen and Cally's son Nicky.

Was there any reason for this? Or was it just because the Final 5 weren't revealed to the other Cylons until very near the end of the series and there was no time for that to be developed into the plot?

Comment: IIRC, it turned out that he *wasn't* the father of the child, and he rather unceremoniously dumps the kid on the real father (probably because the writers realised that they'd written themselves into a corner)

Comment: Oooooh yeah. That's right. He was Hot Dog's son. I had forgotten about that. You're probably right that that was their escape hatch to get out of the corner. LOL . If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The writers seemed to realise that they'd made a mistake in giving the chief a kid (they probably gave him a child before they chose the final five by blindly throwing darts at a wall covered in character photos, but that's just speculation), so it turned out that second-stringer character Hot Dog was the real father all along. Tyrol then unceremoniously dumped the kid on Hot Dog and the kid was never mentioned again.